# Serviço ou pacote para gerar NFe possuindo apenas a chave da Nota Fiscal

Tags: web-service, nfe, pdf, services

Com apenas a chave da NFe eu posso acessar o site da Receita e visualizar a Nota Fiscal em PDF.

É possível utilizar um serviço ou pacote de terceiros que gere tal PDF da mesma maneira que a [Receita oferece](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=), possuindo **apenas a chave** da NFe?

Comment: Tipo isso: https://www.danfeonline.com.br/? Ou tu precisa, por exemplo, de alguma API/WS/Endpoints que tu passe a chave de acesso e recupere o DANFE?

Comment: Sim, uma API ou um link de um serviço (pode ser pago). O objetivo é ter um link que aponta diretamente para o PDF, sem que seja preciso inserir a chave em um form e submetê-lo, como é o caso do danfeonline que funciona bem para o uso manual.

Comment: Conhece o http://www.fsist.com.br/ ?

Comment: @emanuelsn Eu dei uma olhada mas me pareceu meio "gambiarra", não acha?

Comment: Acho. Não sei se para sua necessidade ele é útil.

Comment: A minha necessidade é bem formal: passar um link para o usuário, facilitando o acesso ao PDF. Mas tem que ser uma coisa séria e responsável.